# Loop through a data frame that generate an output based on conditions and values of other columns

Tags: r

A brief version of my df is like the following:

```
A <- c(10,50,50,10,60,70,50,20,60,10)
B <- c(0,3,2,4,1,3,5,1,1,2)
df<- data.frame(A,B)
df
A   B   
10  0
50  3
50  2
10  4
60  1
70  3
50  5
20  1
60  1
10  2
```

I want to generate an output C based on some conditions of column A and values in column B.

Conditions:

1. C=0 when A < 50 or A "just becomes" >= 50
2. C= abs(B[n+1] - B[n]) when both B[n+1] and B[n] are >= 50

Here is an example of what I want in column C:

```
A   B   C   Explaination
10  0   0    A <50, so C=0
50  3   0    A just becomes >= 50, so C is still 0
50  2   1    We have two consecutive A >= 50, so C = abs(2-3) = 1
10  4   0    A <50, so C=0
60  1   0    A just becomes >= 50, so C is still 0
70  3   2    We have two consecutive A >= 50, so C = abs(3-1) = 2
50  5   2    consecutive rows with A >= 50, so C = abs(5-3) = 2
20  1   0    A <50, so C=0
60  1   0    A just becomes >= 50, so C is still 0
10  2   0    A <50, so C=0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's one option, though the logic is a little long-winded:

```
df$C <- ifelse(df$A < 50 | (df$A >= 50 & c(0, head(df$A, -1)) < 50) ,
               0, c(NA, abs(diff(df$B))))
```

Explanation:

- I started with `ifelse(df$A < 50, 0, c(NA, abs(diff(df$B))))`. This gives a 0 if `A < 50` and the differences of the `B`s otherwise (`diff(B)` is one element shorter than `B` itself so I stick a `NA` on the front).
- However this doesn't account for when `A` first exceeds 50, where the value should be 0 still. Note `c(0, head(df$A, -1))` is just elements `2:end` of the `A` column with a `0` stuck on front - it is the "previous" value of `A`. So if `df$A >= 50` and the previous value is `< 50`, then this is the first time we have surpassed 50 and we should get the value 0.

I am sure there are other ways to do it too.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
df%>%mutate(C=ifelse(A<50,0,(ifelse(A>=50 & lag(A)>=50,abs(B-lag(B)),0))))
```